# appCtrl is not a function, got undefined error triggered when trying to load appCtrl (ON THE FLY)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to load controllers on the fly when needed rather than loading them in one go. So, for the I've implemented dynamic approach which works fine without any error. It also works well with Ui-Router. 
But the problem is in Index.html page. I want to put global (super parent) controller name "appCtrl". As this appCtrl should be initialized when I run my app. For that I need to write like ng-controller="appCtrl" or ng-controller="appCtrl as vm" at body tag.

But when I do it, it gives error that appCtrl is a function, got undefined. I tried sever ways but still unable to identify exact error. I have working on this issue since two to three days but still not able to identify it.

I have made this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UDqaD7QKvgqtzgttXLHq?p=preview).

look at body tag of index.html.

main.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "angular": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0-rc.1/angular",
    "ui-router": "//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router"
  },
  shim: {
    "angular": {
      exports: 'angular'
    },
    "ui-router": {
      deps: ['angular']
    }
  }
});

define(
  ['angular',
  'app',
  'controllers/appCtrl'],
  function (angluar, app) {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp'])
});
```

app.js

```
define([
  'angular',
  'ui-router'
], function (angular) {
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);

  function lazy () {
    var self = this;
    this.resolve = function (controller) {
      return { 
        ctrl: ['$q', function ($q) {
          var defer = $q.defer();
          require(['controllers/' + controller], function (ctrl) {
              app.register.controller(controller, ctrl);
              defer.resolve();
          });
          return defer.promise;
        }]
      };
    };
    this.$get = function (){
      return self;
    };
  }
  function config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, 
                   $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, 
                   $filterProvider, $provide, lazyProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state("home", {
        url: "/",
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: 'views/homeView.html',
        resolve: lazyProvider.resolve('homeCtrl')
      });
    app.register = {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
        directive: $compileProvider.directive,
        filter: $filterProvider.register,
        factory: $provide.factory,
        service: $provide.service,
        constant: $provide.constant
    };
  }
  app.provider('lazy', lazy);
  app.config(config);

  return app;
});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.17/require.js" data-main="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appCtrl as vm"> // I want this to work correctly but it is not getting loaded dynamically. I don't know why. Help me to resolve it.

    <a ui-sref="home">go home</a>
    <ui-view></ui-view>

    {{vm.appVar}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On your index.html page, your requireJS is called only and then configure your angular framework, So after rendering of index.html page your angular framework is build, that's why you are not able to call appCtrl in index.html page.

Comment: any help? remove ng-app="appCtrl" code from body tag and run it and click on go home link. It works fine. But I want to load appCtrl somehow when page is getting loaded. If you have solution please update my plunkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually missing the controller statement in your controller code.
Use the following code

```
define(['app'], function (app){ //Updated Line
  console.log('app controller loaded');
  app.controller('appCtrl',ctrl); //New Line added
  ctrl.$inject = ['$http'];
  function ctrl ($http) {
    this.appVar = 'hi from appCtrl';
  };
  return ctrl;
});
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6qWkt2bqR7GWsjyHumQt?p=preview)

Comment: I have a question here. Why other controllers don't need this line and why appCtrl does?

Comment: Very good question. I do not have answer. You can post a new question for that here and wait for the other people to answer. Don't forget to tag this question also.

Comment: What do you mean by don't forget to tag this question also? what is that?

Comment: I mean to say, Create a new Question with proper query and put this question link there.

Comment: What I understand is, I'm going to add appCtrl manually. I mean no controller kinda stuff is defined at route.config. So we have to tell angular that appCtrl is a controller and we have to register it before using it. while for other controllers, look at .resolve method it takes controller name as a parameter and register then before using it. still I'm not sure about it.